# How to calculate Maximum Flow in graph that has infinite capacities

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I want to implement a method that calculate "maximum flow" in any graph including one infinite-capacity at least. I used to import NetworkX library whenever there is graph processing but unfortunately it does not take in consideration infinite capacity yet according to the description of [maximum_flow](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.flow.maximum_flow.html):

> ...  If the graph has a path of infinite capacity, the value of a feasible flow on the graph is unbounded above and the function raises a NetworkXUnbounded.

So, my questions:

- How to implement simply Max-Flow with infinite capacity ?
- Is it possible to adapt NetworkX's method for this  ?

Any other suggestions are welcomed.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a flow network in which some edges have infinite capacity. There are two possible options:

1. There’s a path from the source to the sink of infinite-capacity edges. In that case, a maximum flow can be found by pushing infinite flow across that path. You can’t improve that flow by pushing more flow across other edges, since you already have infinite flow!
2. No infinite-capacity path exists in the network. Then there’s an upper bound to how much total flow can be pushed in the network (a quick proof: consider the cut formed by taking the start node and everything reachable by infinite-capacity edges as one part of the cut, and everything else as the other part; then the max flow is bounded by the capacity of that cut). In this case, the infinite-capacity edges function essentially as “you can push as much flow across this edge as you’d like,” but there’s no flow path that could actually have infinite flow across it. So take each infinite-capacity edge and replace it with an edge that has enormous but finite capacity (say, the sum of all the capacities of the finite-capacity edges). Now, a max flow in this modified graph gives you the max flow in the original network.

Hope this helps!